# Sharing an object (between users) with Parse SDK

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I want to implement a share feature in my app via an ActivityViewController.  The data I want to share is just a simple dictionary of strings similar to this example:

```
My stores : [
     Abercrombie : [
          Jeans : 32
          Polo  : small
     ]
     American Eagle : [
          jeans : 31 
          Polo : extra small
     ]
```

I would think the Parse SDK would have prepackaged way to do this (similar to the validation email Parse gives you for free) but looking around in the IOS guide I really can't find anything?  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by share a dictionary of strings? Are you trying to share using Facebook? Twitter? Instagram? Text message? Email? There are so many ways that you could possibly interpret "share feature" that you need to give more details.

Comment: Thank you, I've revised my question with an example of what I'm trying to share... I think that Email would be the best use case for this type of data

Comment: As you've realized, there are so many formats which could be used to share/distribute information. That's the reason why Parse hasn't included some generic means to do it. If you are wanting to use email, I would recommend creating a Cloud Code function to format your data however you want and then use the Mailgun module to send out the emails

Comment: @Russell good point, thanks for the suggestions!